# Storing an indexPath in a NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdictionary

I would like to store an `NSIndexPath` an Array of `NSDictionaries` for later to compare.

I know that I can do it by storing 2 numbers as 2 keys

```
NSNumber *selRow = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInteger:indexPath.row]; 
NSNumber *selSection = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInteger:indexPath.section];
```

But that way I couldn't filter the filter the array in one run.

Is there a way to store (and get back) the `NSIndexPath` directly?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you store it directly? `NSIndexPath` is an object, so it's ok. You can see on the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSIndexPath_Class/Reference/Reference.html) that inherits from `NSObject`.

Comment: +1, Correct, in this way you can access both row and section whenever you want.

Comment: I suspect the overabundance of caution was perhaps from seeing somewhere that `NSIndexPath` can't go in a property list dictionary, in which case it's common to store two numbers.